# ADFS roles from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs, claims

Scenario: In an intranet application, ADFS uses AD for authentication(Account Store) and Sql server for authorization(roles/Attribute Store).

The roles are my own application specific. There are other applications that need to use ADFS. If ADFS is configured to use my SQL Server to fetch roles, what would other applications do? How will they manage their authorization?

Is my understanding correct? If yes, please verify my answer:

Ans: ADFS just returns me the AD identifier(SID/Name).I map this to my sql server roles. Role management should be done by my own application connecting to Sql server. Use session to prevent hitting DB for authorization every time.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hitting the SQL server for every authorization check, you could implement claims based authentication. Use the SQL attribute store to add your role claims to the AD user ID claims. The resulting claims ticket (SAML) is sent as a cookie and isn't fetched on every authentication check as it is kept as a cookie by the user browser available to the server on each and every request. The timeout/refresh can be set by ajusting the claims ticket TTL (time to live).
Just a suggestion... =o)

Comment: The question was on ownership of DB used in sql attribute store. Would that be used by other applications accessign ADFS? Consider a large enterprise where 100s of appication uses the same ADFS.